# Why did Sator use inverted Sator in retriving briefcase?

Tags: tenet

Here is the mind blowing car chase scene:

[image]

If Protagonist and Sator agree deal before in exchange of plutonium 241
for gold bars then why did Sator use inverted Sator in this scene?

Comment: Sator went through the mission twice. It was a temporal pincer operation. He goes through the mission with his henchmen, then winds back time and goes through the mission again, this time with better knowledge of what 'happened' so as to come out on top. His future self realises that he was betrayed and he never received the package.